# How does FileInputStream find the file?

Tags: java, windows, file-io

I'm designing a program that needs to read a file from a folder that contains roughly 10^8 files.

How does FileInputStream find the desired file from it's provided filename?  Does it work similarly to a hashmap with O(1) lookup time, or does it linearly traverse the files in the given folder until it finds a match?

I imagine this might have more to do with how windows file storage works than with FileInputStream, but I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: Consider using `SimpleFileVisitor` for this. [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)

Comment: How big are the files?  Keep in mind that on NTFS the minimum allocation unit is 4096 bytes, so with 10^8 files the average disk space overhead is going to be about 200GB.

Answer (score 4):

The file name is passed to the OS, and it reads the directory looking for a matching name.  It might optimise the lookup but Java doesn't get involved.

You might consider breaking the files into multiple directories and ideally using less files.  Opening and closing lots of small files spends most of it's time opening and closing the file descriptor. The finding and reading is usually much smaller.

Comment: Further info:  I'm effectively attempting to use a directory as a SuperHashMap, with filenames as keys and serialized files as objects.

The problem at hand requires a very low number of reads/writes to this SuperHashMap, so the problem of opening and closing many files isn't present, but the hope is by pushing the responsibility for data management onto the OS, I can prevent the program from needing to load what would effectively be a 10GB object when on any individual run of the program we should only need to access maybe 20 files.

Given this situation... opinion?

Comment: @gravityplanx while not as efficient as I would like, this would appear to work. Having many files is likely to be the simplest.  I would consider making a directory for each of the first 3-4 characters. As this might improve the performance of your program and any tools which you use on this directory.

Answer (score 3):

It asks the operating system to find the file.  How does the operating system do it?  It depends on the OS, and on the file system.  In at least some cases, the answer is, "Yes, it works like a HashMap."  On the other hand, I know of at least some OS/filesystem combinations that get seriously bogged down once you have more than a few thousand files in the same directory.

Comment: Any idea where I can find a efficiency lookup by operating system to see where this is safe or where I would run into trouble?

Comment: Can't you just test it, @gravityplanx. Just cd to another directory and do a `type <path-to-some-file>`. If this is fast, then so will be Java.

Comment: @Ingo  I haven't created the 10GB file structure yet, and would prefer to avoid doing so if it's a dead end.  And without a folder of that size, it's hard to tell how efficient this will be.

Comment: I'm working right now on a product that potentially keeps thousands of files on disk.  We compute a two-character hash of each filename, and use the hash as the name of a subdirectory where the file is stored.  For millions of files, I would generalize that to more than one level of subdirectory.

Comment: @gravityplanx You don't have it yet?  Don't do it, then. I have experience with very large directories, that hold up to a million files. A simple `ls -lt` will take minutes before it even starts to print to the screen, as the sorting takes so long. A File Explorer will simply get stuck when it needs to show such a directory. But 10^8 files? A simple directory listing will just use up tons of memory, not to speak of CPU. Avoid at all costs! Use a multi-level directory structure.